# No route matches error in Rails 4 for 'like' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm getting an error in my app that I can't seem to fix. I keep getting Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/recipes/1/like". The issue I can't figure out is, why it's going through as a get request rather than a post?

Here is my code;
routes

```
  #recipe routes
  resources :recipes do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    member do
      post 'like'
      post 'review'
    end
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
  end
```

recipes controller

```
  def like 
    like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: @user, recipe: @recipe)
    if like.valid?
      flash[:success] = "Your selection was successful"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:danger] = "#{@user} " + 'you can only like/dislike once per item.'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

view

```
        <div class="pull-right">
            <%= link_to like_recipe_path(@recipe, like: true), method: :post do %>
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> &nbsp; 
                <%= @recipe.thumbs_up_total %> 
            <%end %> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <%= link_to like_recipe_path(@recipe, like: false), method: :post do %> 
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> &nbsp; <%= @recipe.thumbs_down_total %>
            <%end %>
        </div>
```

rake routes

```
like_workout_path   POST    /workouts/:id/like(.:format)    workouts#like
like_recipe_path    POST    /recipes/:id/like(.:format) recipes#like
```

when i inspect the button

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/recipes/1/like?like=true">
                        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> &nbsp; 
                        0 
                    </a>
```

I've inspected the link, and it does have an action of post when rendered, however when I click it, it takes me to this routing error page. Can someone please explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: As [API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to): "_Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET._". Your code is look ok, may be you should check your browser setting?

Comment: Did you inspect the link in browser console? Does it has `data-method="post"`?

Comment: in which controller yr `like` method ?

Comment: @hoangdd javascript seems to be enabled (it works elsewhere in the app)

Comment: @Pavan when i inspect it does give me post as the data-method

Comment: @Mirv could this be another issue around javascript not loading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

POST-ing using `link_to`
Sending a post request via a link is something that the html `<a href>` cannot do. You can only use it to make `GET` requests, not `POST`. That being said, Rails has some magic tricks for you.

By providing the `:method => :post` option, Rails will create a **form** and **submit** it via **javascript**. Note that you need the `jquery-rails gem` for this to work, if you don’t have it, there won’t be any magic happening and your links will default to a GET request.

```
<%= link_to "Post", root_path, :method => :post %>
# => <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/">Post</a>


#Adding more params to the POST request
<%= link_to "Create User", users_path(:email => "jdoe@email.com", :password => "secret"), :method => :post %>
# => <a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/users?email=jdoe%40email.com&amp;password=secret">Create User</a>
```

Or you can use `form_tag`

```
# not tested, maybe will have syntax issue
<%= form_tag(like_recipe_path, {:method => :post}) do %>
  <%= contant_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-thumbs-o-up", "aria-hidden": true, :onclick => "this.form.submit();") %>
  <%= @recipe.thumbs_up_total %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried the bottom code but it doesn't seem to create anything clickable for me. Its gives me the thumb but nothing else. The weird thing is my code used to work but since having to clone from my github repo things have been randomly breaking.

Comment: @J.Schimdt I'm going to guess that your repo has a different setup for the gemfile or perhaps an .ignore file for github blocked it ... if your local version is working, you should try trouble shooting that to get it propagating across all machines.  Sometimes a `bundle update` command and then push the changes will work versus a `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your github & you have the jquery enabled there - my browser is enabled for javascript ... I get the same error at first - I got the first error working by just adding the 'get' routes to `config/routes.rb` the project ...

```
...
      #recipe routes
      resources :recipes do
        collection do
          get 'search'
        end
        member do
          match 'recipes/:id' => 'recipes#like', via: [:get, :post]
          match 'review/:id' => 'recipes#review', via: [:get, :post]
        end
        resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index]
      end
...
```

This opens up the doors to more errors and questions of course ... such as on your table for `schema.rb` ...

```
 ...
     create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.boolean  "like"
        t.integer  "chef_id"
        t.integer  "recipe_id"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.integer  "workout_id"
      end
...
```

...of course it still leaves holes in the programming style in your recipe controller for the `like` action you are using ...

`like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: @user, recipe: @recipe)`

When you have `chef_id` instead of `user_id` ... which means your code should probably be ...

`like = Like.create(like: params[:like], chef_id: @user, recipe: @recipe)`

(of course this means you have to adjust database schema etc)

Unless of course it's the id of the user who is likes the recipe, in which case your controller and schema need to be adjusted after the routing issue is done.

Comment: Thanks @Mirv, i added the 'get' like to routes.rb and that seemed to fix it up :)

Comment: @J.Schimdt You can mark this as answered if you feel it was the fix or just upvote it if it helped but didn't fix it :)